# Using QtClasses in Visual Studio

Tags: qt, visual-c++

I am creating an application that uses Qtxlsx writer to transfer data from excel to my own datatype.  Can I simply #include the QVariant Class headers or any Q classes headers I need into excel?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Qt Xlsx module as described [there](http://qtxlsx.debao.me/building.html). The library supposed to be used in your project just like a set of source code files. And, of course, you can include any headers in your Qt application.